# Chrome adding no-cache header when href is clicked

Tags: google-chrome, caching, cache-control

I have an href in my page like:

```
<a href="/mysection"> My Section </a>
```

when I click it, Chrome makes the request with a the following header:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
```

which makes the request by-pass all cache layers, so I get a 200 status code for resources that should be cached (so I should receive a 304)

I've tested the same app with firefox and it doesn't add the Cache-Control header, so I'm getting my 304 status codes as spected.

How can I make Chrome not to add no-cache header on href's clicks? is this the default behavior?

Chrome version: 27.0.1453.110

Firefox version: 24.0

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I had cache disabled from chrome config. No that I've enabled it, I'm getting "200 (from cache)" as expected

Comment: Should not you be getting 304 - Not Modified ?

PS: It happened to me too when I disabled cache in google developer tools.

Comment: I think I'm not getting 304 because the request isn't actually going to the server, so it doesn't really know if the resource has not been modified, it only knows that it has to be retrieved form local cache